# Code for transfering the table content from localserver to remote server DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
$dbhost1 = "10.0.11.211";
$dbuser1 = "root";
$dbpassword1 = "";
$db1 = "product";
$connection1 = mysqli_connect($dbhost1, $dbuser1, $dbpassword1) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection1, $db1);

//MySQL Server 2
$dbhost2 = "localhost";
$dbuser2 = "root";
$dbpassword2 = "";
$db2 = "product";
$connection2 = mysqli_connect($dbhost2, $dbuser2, $dbpassword2) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection2, $db2);
$sql = "insert into 10.0.11.211.product.inserting select * from localhost.product.inserting";
$result = mysqli_query($connection1, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "connection error";
}
?>
```

How can I correct this code? Actually I connected to servers at time.

Comment: you can't do it this way

Comment: then how can we do

Comment: if u having any example code please send me the through the link

Answer (score 2):

You can setup [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html), which is basically linking a table on one server to a table on another. Then use the federation to do your data transfers.

> First, you must have a table on the remote server that you want to
> access by using a FEDERATED table. Suppose that the remote table is in
> the federated database and is defined like this:
>
> You need to change database host and database/table name as per your details

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Next, create a FEDERATED table on the local server for accessing the remote table:
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://root@10.0.11.211:9306/federated/test_table';
```

Then you can query it like any other table.

There are however a decent number of [limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html) you should read about including the remote password being stored in plain text. If this was a temporary setup purely for a once off copy, and the server isn't available to the public you have already minimised most of the risk associated with it though.